# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am getting the below exception in 3rd statement, I am trying to read a file but it doesn't allow me to open read stream.

This is just sample code but the actual scenario is different, web socket is trying to write bytes into the file and other process(music player) is trying to read the bytes from the same file. I want to achieve this scenario.

```
      IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            var writeStream = storage.OpenFile("sample.txt", 
                                                System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                                                System.IO.FileAccess.Write, 
                                                System.IO.FileShare.Read);

            var readStream = storage.OpenFile("sample.txt", 
                                                System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
                                                System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
```

> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException was caught
>        HResult=-2146233264
>        Message=Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.
>        Source=mscorlib
>       StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode                            mode, FileAccess access, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
>          at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>          at FileReadWriteSample.MainPage.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   InnerException:

Comment: Try providing the `System.IO.FileShare.Read` parameter to your second `OpenFile` call and see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is give a file access permission for read stream as well. It solves my problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/f9e55760-e533-4124-a7ed-7f8f15e00e60

Answer (score 3):

You already have a stream open for that file (through the second statement). You need to dispose that stream first before you can open another stream.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/f9e55760-e533-4124-a7ed-7f8f15e00e60